# In modern webbrowsers is there any point in putting www infront of a url that uses it?

Tags: browser, url

When going to `www.facebook.com` or `www.cbc.ca` is there any benefit or difference made by omitting the `www`?

EDIT: so it could be a problem if `www` is omitted but not automatically added, could it ever be a problem if `www` is added but not required?

Comment: See here: http://no-www.org/

Comment: See here: http://www.yes-www.org/

Comment: Nah, see here: [extra-www.org](http://www.www.extra-www.org/)

Comment: That might be a question regarding [user experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I've always been amused that the acronym "www" requires far more syllables to pronounce (at least in English) than the entire phrase it replaces. At least it is easy to type... :-)

Comment: @gparyani It is interesting that [www.no-www.org](http://www.no-www.org) works!

Comment: @Nazar554 It's a redirect to the non-www version.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that an extra-extra-www.org site will spring up soon (e.g. `www.www.www.example.com`).

Comment: @RBerteig I know some people who pronounce it "triple-U" for that reason.  Not sure if that'll ever catch on...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I generally never say it at all because the convention seems to be these days that with or without it leads to the same place.

Comment: dub-dub-dub was common for a while - what happened to that?

Comment: try http://vim.org vs. http://www.vim.org

Comment: @sehe I get redirected to the same site with a black kid holding a drill.

Comment: @Celeritas the first link is dead. If you get redirected, it's your browser doing you "favours"

Comment: @sehe isn't this bizarre, in Firefox the first link USUALLY works if I click it with the middle mouse button and open it in a new tab, otherwise it doesn't. It also works if I right click on it and select new tab.

Comment: @Celeritas oh joy. Go file some bugs at mozilla. Really, I suppose it could be construed a security issue to open a different link from what the user clicked. Meh.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I love that yes-www seems to be saying we should use www to remind people of the difference between hypertext transfer protocol and other internet protocols. It's a shame, really, that no one ever thought to just put http in web URLs just to make it clear ... ;)

Comment: @chris-l: Nice to see that they _redirect_ [www.extra-www.org](http://www.extra-www.org) and [extra-www.org](http://extra-www.org) to [www.www.extra-www.org](http://www.www.extra-www.org) :-)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I usually pronounce it woo-woo-woo and that is usually understood in context.

Answer (score 80):

> In modern webbrowsers is there any point in putting www infront of a url that uses it? When going to www.facebook.com or www.cbc.ca is there any benefit or difference made by omitting the www?

It usually doesn’t, but it *could*.

This has nothing to do with the browser; it has to do with the web-server. The web-server is a computer (or even multiple computers) which receive queries for web-pages and send the appropriate data. A URL includes several parts, one of which is the name or address of the web-server.

Many companies host more than just a web-server, they may also run an FTP-server, a database-server, a mail-server, and so on. These could be hosted from the same machine as the web-server or on different machines.

In the past, it was common to specify the difference via a prefix for consistency. So for example, Acme Industries might buy the domain-name `acme.org`, then set up one *or more* computers to host the different service they have. When you want to use one of the services, you enter the appropriate host name:

```
 www.acme.org - Acme’s web-site
 ftp.acme.org - Acme’s file server
 sql.acme.org - Acme’s database server
 pop.acme.org - Acme’s incoming mail server
smtp.acme.org - Acme’s outgoing mail server
```

So why does it still work without `www.`? Because most web-servers allow you to accept different URLs and [redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) them as necessary. For the convenience of users, most companies and organizations set up a rule to have have the web-server handle connections to the hostname on port 80 (the “web port”) or redirect it to another system if the web-server is a different machine.

Differentiating the service or machine being accessed can also be done through the port, but it requires specifically including it in the name, so it’s not really any better than using prefixes:

```
acme.org:80     - web-server
acme.org:21     - file server
```

Sometimes the scheme can perform this function:

```
http://acme.org - web-server
ftp://acme.org  - file server
```

Using schemes works as well and can be done automatically using the appropriate software (e.g., a browser would add `http://`, an email client would add `pop://`, etc.), but there are not official schemes for every type of server that can exist, and inventing one is not ideal because it would require software to support it.

It’s becoming less and less necessary to include `www.`, but it is not universal and some sites still require it because helps keep things organized.

Comment: Depending on the setup, the redirections might actually be happening on the DNS level. In fact, that's the default setup with at least one major domain provider. Also, if the redirect *was* on the webserver level, you'd still need DNS entries both the domain and its `www` subdomain towards the webserver anyway (though this does allow more control for different services/ports).

Comment: Yes, there are different ways that it can happen now and it can get quite complex and confusing. `:-/` That said, when the Internet’s foundations were first being designed (and later when URLs were being standardized), there was no ICANN or even IANA and sub-domains really did refer to actual, physical machines. These days they can all be hosted from the same system or even a whole cluster.

Comment: it's a pity that SRV records can't used for HTTP until 1.2 at the earliest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063378/why-do-browsers-not-use-srv-records

Comment: On a side note, sometimes browsers _do_ have something to do with this: In Firefox, if the non-www domain is unreachable,  the browser will try to load the www subdomain. For example loading `example.invalid` will also load `www.example.invalid` without any server redirects.

Comment: @kapep, yes, some browsers will try to be helpfull and add schemes and prefixes automatically. For example, in Chrome, if you enter `microsoft` and press `Ctrl`+`Enter`, Chrome will add `http://www.` and `.com`. However I meant that the *requirement* for them has nothing to do with the browser, it is up to the server whether it will work or not.

Answer (score 15):

Yes and no. The www is 'just' a subdomain thats used for websites commonly, and unfortunately not all companies set up their second level domain to be accessible without it.

If the address you're going to *has* a www subdomain *and* its not set up to allow its second level then its necessary. Else no.

As for how you set it up, there's both schools of thought that [www is not needed](http://no-www.org/) and [that it does](http://www.yes-www.org/). There's little reason *not* to set up your domain records to point at the www less second level domain. www is probably obsolete in this day and age but it dosen't hurt to have it. In my case, I personally don't have www domains but thats due to laziness more than anything else.

Comment: I think a subdomain and a cname are different things. The `www` is a cname, not a subdomain.

Comment: A cname is *merely* a type of record like an A name or a AAAA name, just that it points to another domain name, rather than an IP address. There's nothing magical or special about the www subdomain that makes it always a cname - I typically set them as A names or AAAA names.

Comment: Yes, that is right, but no one sets up the `www` as a subdomain, where that is something different than the regular domain. It is confusing to call it a subdomain, because of convention, not because it technically is one or not. Though, technically, the `www` is not the cname either, but that feels too technical for this question.

Comment: technically foo.bar is a subdomain of .bar, which is a top level domain (that annoyingly will likely exist soon), and www.foo.bar is a subdomain of foo.bar. We're splitting hairs here but a cname is a *type of domain record* rather than a *type of domain*.

Comment: @fredsbend - actually its common to set up www as a subdomain, as it provides better performance - one less DNS lookup.  Look no further then Google as an example of this.  Their www records are A records as are their base domains.  The same is true for superuser.com and slashdot.com They are by no means unique or different to the norm.

Comment: @fredsbend It can be setup either way,using an A record can save a query and for large traffic websites that can be a significant resource savings.

Comment: I would call "www" a *host name*. Whether the record is implemented as an a record or a cname is irrelevant. The host is named "www", and the domain is "facebook.com".

A host name refers to *one* physical system, whereas a subdomain or domain refers to a *group* of systems.

Comment: I disagree there - though I think the difference is minor.  You can have more than one system with the same hostname - for example with round robin load balancing. You could also choose to have a different domain name and hostname for a system, and the hostname isn't necessarily a FQDN. On the internet, no one needs to know your hostname is dog.

Comment: @TomXP411: According to that naming `facebook.com` is a domain, but `facebook` is also _host_ name in domain `com`, because `facebook.com` has an A record in addition to SOA and NS ones. And yes, that was one of the reasons why there used to always be `www`—to avoid mixing SOA+NS records with other types. According to DNS parlance, all records are called domains though.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Acknowledged. While technically, a hostname is a form of domain name, there's a difference in their purpose. I'll never use the term "domain" to refer to a single endpoint. That's a "host", even if that host is a load-balanced group that responds to a single IP address. Whether facebook.com is also a hostname... well, there's a reason we put www in front of domain names - to distinguish the web servers from the ftp servers and other servers on a network. That facebook.com is synonymous with www.facebook.com is merely a convenience and shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: I see it as the other way around - I consider having a www in front of a domain name to be an anachronism, and that unless you have multiple servers with the same roles that need to be seperated, I'd expect that using the 'main' domain should get me where I logically expect to. If I run journeymangeek.com on say, 3 servers , I'd expect www.journeymangeek.com and journeymangeek.com to work for the website, and any resource all of them need to serve identically and 1.journeymangeek.com 2.journeymangeek.com and 3.journeymangeek.com for specific resources like ftp and ssh. I guess we veer into

Comment: Best practices, philosophy and a tiny bit of religion at this point. I wouldn't consider using the www subdomain as part of a hostname *essential* (for that matter, I favour computer/role specific hostnames over FQDNs). They're nice to have. I do grumble, and adjust when a website isn't accessible over the 'main' domain name however.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, companies redirect "domain.com" to "www.domain.com", but that's not a required standard, and it's not always followed.

While you do most of your internet interaction through a web browser, there's other stuff on the Internet besides web pages. While nearly all of this is wrapped up in web pages today, there's still FTP, Telnet, Gopher, news servers, mail servers, SIP (voice over IP) and a few other fun protocols. Anyone remember Finger?

Since all of these services were different, each had a unique hostname assigned to it by convention: you could always count on finding an FTP server at ftp.netscape.net, their gopher server was gopher.netscape.net, and so on.

Of course, in the 80's and early 90's, a server computer cost more than a luxury car. So www.company.com and ftp.company.com *probably* pointed to the same place, since the entire company would have just a single Internet server.

Then something big happened. In the 90's: server computers got cheaper, and expensive mainframes and minicomputers gave way to commodity systems that cost less than a weekend at Disneyland. Any desktop machine could be a web server, thanks to free Linux, and people started building out their server farms with multiple PC's. Today, you can build a web server for less than $100, and store it in a soda can (hopefully an empty one.)

So the Internet exploded: Facebook today gets more hits in one day than the entirety of the Internet did in 1995. So we use more than one server to handle web requests: entire *groups* of computers these days will respond to a single host name, thanks to the magic of load balancing, and the Internet seems to have settled on a standard of doing all of our Internet work through a web browser.

What this means is that www.domain.com is no longer on the same computer as ftp.domain.com. So where do we send requests to the "naked" domain of "domain.com"?

Today, people think of "the web" as "the Internet", and so they use a browser for everything they do. That's convenient, since having separate programs for downloading files, reading news, checking email, reading blogs, and checking the weather can be a real pain. It also brings up questions like "why do we have www in front of web pages?" This means that we can usually get away with assuming that a request for a naked domain is the same as a request for that domain's www server.

So now, most companies will respond to naked requests by redirecting "domain.com" to "www.domain.com". However, there's no standard that requires it, and you'll frequently find that small domains hosted on server farms won't respond to naked domains that way. (For example, one hosting company I used dropped users to the hosting company's landing page when someone typed just "mydomain.com".)

Luckily for the lazy among us, there's a keyboard shortcut in most browsers that lets you shorten the process even more: just type "company", press Control-Enter, and the browser expands it to "www.company.com".

Comment: That's a good point about users asking why we have `www` in front of addresses. Practically the only time an end user sees a URL is in their browser, which almost always goes to a `www`. Once you start writing web application or administering networks, you quickly "discover" all sorts of non-`www` URLs. People ask why they have `www` in their web page, but nobody asks why they have to add the `smtp` and `pop` to their URL when configuring Thunderbird.

Comment: Back when webmail was becoming a thing (rather than using stand-alone mail clients like Outlook), I told a user to get her email by pointing her browser at "mail.mydomain.com". She kept telling me it wasn't working. After 2 days of go-arounds, she finally showed me a screen shot. She was typing "www.mail.mydomain.coim". Sometimes, you just can't win.

Answer (score 3):

The domain name part of URLs is read backwards. So `www.example.com/index.html` is actually like `com/example/www/index.html` in terms who is "inside" who.

Many sites have a `www` subdomain, but they may also have other subdomains such as `ftp`, `secure`, `members`, `forum`, `us`, `fr`, `china` and so on. These are all different from each other, and `www.example.com` is also a different address from `example.com` (there's no rule saying `example.com` should be interpreted as `www.example.com` and not, for instance, `store.example.com`).

> What happens if I don't add the `www`?

Usually, nothing. People who run websites realize that everyone is going to forget it all the time, so they configure their site to make `www.example.com` and `example.com` point to the same place (by redirecting).

Once in a blue moon you may run into a site that won't work without the `www` because the person running it didn't do the configuration. So you will be able to access `http://www.example.com` but `http://example.com` will return an error.

> What happens if I put in an extra `www`?

Same as above, except switch around which URL works and which doesn't.

Also, technically, you are supposed to include the `http://` part as well, so any address you enter is incomplete anyway whether you enter the `www` or not. The browser will have to infer what you meant in both cases - so it may infer that the `www` was meant to be included.

Sites where the `www` matters are very rare nowadays, but I know I've encountered a few in the past 2-3 years. I can't remember what they were right now.

Answer (score 0):

As a sysadmin, if you want to use CDN Services for speed up your web service, you can't use any combination of dns rules together.

To use a CDN, you must use a dns Cname, so you need to create a Cname for acme.org, but if you want to receive Mail with user@acme.org, you can't have a cname for acme.org. Then you must use a subdomain www for the web server, so as sysadmin is mandatory to have a www record.

Modern browsers hidden to you the need for write the www part, but this part can be necessary for a website with a high visit rate. The rules for internet are old, but are our rules.

Answer (score 0):

There are the issues dealing with the variety of smartphones and small-screened tablet devices (sorry, but I cannot force myself to type the iWords) that are now browsing the web.

Generally the prefixes of `mobi.` or `m.` are used (instead of `www.`) in order to provide web pages that are tailored to the smaller screens.

Who hasn't run into the issue of trying to navigate a large scaled web page on a small device (scroll, scroll, scroll)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of rubbish being talked here.

The thing containing a "www." (or not) is a DNS name and hence subject to some very specific rules. Notably that you can't have two names of different record types unless one of the records is an A or an AAA record. If you want to receive emails at **example.com** then you must have an MX record for **example.com**. But browsers won't search for MX records when trying to find a website, they only look for CNAME, AAA and A records. So if a site has an MX record it cannot have a CNAME with the same name. The problem with A records is that they only point to a single host - and the layer of abstraction provided by CNAMEs is important for load balancing and disaster recovery. Cloudflare (for example) allow you to configure DNS records as if a CNAME were permitted and [convert this to an A record on the fly](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-Understand-and-configure-CNAME-Flattening).

Answer (score -1):

Building on what has been mentioned already, most corporate/private servers will automatically redirect to WWW. On the other hand many, if not most, .GOV and .MIL sites will not. In those cases you usually receive one of many error messages. These sites also usually do not automatically redirect to HTTPS: from HTTP: even when needed.

Comment: Not correct.  See, for example: usa.gov, whitehouse.gov, etc.